# How can i copy tables+content from db A to db B when db B is being rebuild every night?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2016, visual-studio-2022, biml

I have two databases: A and B.
I have read only access to Database A, full control on Database B.
They are on the same server.
Database A is rebuild every night.

Using BIML Express all schemas and tables are copied from database A into database B.

Existing tables in database B are overwritten by the corresponding ones in database A.
Objects in database B that do not exist in Database A are left untouched.
For policy reasons we cannot query Database A, except for copying the contents once in the morning.

Using BIML Express we created a SSIS package doing the dropping, creating and filling of the tables.
Whenever something changed in Database A we would be informed, run the BIML scripts and thus generate a new package incorporating the changes.

However, we no longer can use BIML since we are migrating company wide to Visual Studio 2022. We have to adapt the SSIS package manually from now on whenever there is a change in database A. Since changes are fairly frequent this is a lot of work.

Is there another way of doing this automatically? Since database A is rebuild every night I see hurdles using replication.

The server at the moment is SQL Server 2016, will be upgraded in the coming weeks to 2019.

Just to be clear, I am in no way beholden to Visual Studio, SSIS, BIML.
Just looking for a solution with no extra price tag since this is temporary.

Comment: The title asks one thing, the text something completely different. Copying tables is the job of Replication. What you really ask is how to use SSIS projects in Visual Studio. Well .... you'll have to move away from SSIS sooner rather than later. Visual Studio still supports SSIS projects [through an extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSIS.SqlServerIntegrationServicesProjects) BUT MS itself has essentially abandoned SSIS, pushing Azure services like Data Factory or alternative options like DataBricks instead.

Comment: There haven't been any new SSIS features since SQL Server 2016 and even the SSIS extension lags behind Visual Studio *a lot* - it's tested against VS 2019 instead of 2022.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, there is now a GA SSIS extension for VS 2022 but I agree SSIS hasn't gotten much love lately.

Comment: @DanGuzman do you have a link? I checked the SSIS link just now, even searched twice to make sure. The page says `Tested against Visual Studio 2019 16.11`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, the [SQL Server Integration Services Projects 2022 release notes](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSIS.MicrosoftDataToolsIntegrationServices) says `Tested against Visual Studio 2022 17.5`.

Comment: This doesn't even appear in the first 100 results for SSIS .......... And anyway, the current VS version is 17.7.3, not 17.5. For the last 5-6 years it seems we have to keep two VS versions side by side, one just for SSIS, and one for everything else

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, nope, not asking how to use SSIS. Asking how to accomplish the stated goal: copying tables with contents from db A to db B when B is being rebuild every night. If I can solve that using replication, please explain how. And with regards to the future: I am talking now about an actual situation. There is no way you can distill from this question what our roadmap is for the future. For all you know this might be part of a 2-year project to move away from MS altogether. But that is irrelevant to the question since I now have to handle losing BIML.

Comment: @Henrov what do you mean by `Using BIML we created ...` ? BIML itself is the XML dialect. BIDS Helper, BIML Script etc were separate tools that generated that XML. Which one are you using? Few of them are still around though

Comment: `Asking how to accomplish the stated goal` you've already achieved that in your SSIS package, which is stored as a BIML XML and still works in VS 2022. Automatically generating that SSIS package was the work of a separate tool. What tool?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos We used BIML Express. We started the BIML scripts manually which was about 10 minutes work generating an new package and deploying it.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos https://support.varigence.com/forums/bimlexpress-forum/082031ba-cefa-ec11-a81b-000d3a0001df

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I see you changed the question title. I am in no way beholden to use SSIS for this! It is just that that was used until now!

Comment: @Henrov the title made no sense as I said. The question wasn't about copying tables at all. It's somewhat related to BIML, SSIS's XML dialect at all. And frankly, it's borderline out-of-scope - you're asking for a product recommendation for a free BIML Express replacement in Visual Studio 2022. *BIML* is still there. It's BIML Express that's gone

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Are you now telling me what my question is? I do not care if the solution can be reached using PHP, a cat and a bag of carrots. I just described the process as it is.  Please remove VS from the title of this question, VS is no requirement at all and neither is SSIS.

Comment: @Henrov Python would be the answer then, probably with `dbt`. BIML is the file format of SSIS and SSIS only works inside Visual Studio. Are you saying BIML itself is not a requirement? The question text *definitely* doesn't reflect that. I suggest editing the question yourself to make clear what you actually want

Comment: To answer the exact title, without looking at the question `Either use Replication or use dbt and Python`

Comment: Will replication work if the database A is being rebuild every night? I thought the need for foreign keys and replicating needing to be setup makes replication unusable in this scenario. Python may be a good way to go

Comment: What does `rebuild` mean? Replication is a server, not a database feature. If you want to copy everything, backup/restore is probably faster. If tables are deleted and recreated, or truncated and refilled, you can create a snapshot replication that copies all data every day. This isn't new technology, so why wasn't it used before? Are there other restrictions? Why was a per-table script chosen?

Comment: Rebuild means that all objects within the database are dropped and rebuild.
Backup/Restore was not an option since objects created in Database B (that might not exist in database A) should not be dropped and cannot be rebuild from code.
My understanding was that replication creates keys in the source database which is a NoGo. Hence the choice at that time to create SSISdtxes using BIML.